# How do I run a PHP cronjob every 15 min with 30 sec duration in cPanel?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a PHP script like

```
domain.com/xxx.php
```

I set a cron to every 15 minutes with a website (cronjob.org), but it only visit to my PHP script and its duration is like 1 to 2 seconds.

But my cronjob needs a 30 seconds duration (must visit my PHP script for 30 seconds and wait for another job).
How do I create the PHP script and how do I put it in my cPanel like the following?

```
domain.com/yyy.php
```

When I set cronjob with (cronjob.org) for every 15 min to

```
domain.com/yyy.php
```

it visits my original PHP script

```
domain.com/xxx.php
```

with 30 seconds duration.

Comment: 15 mins or  30 sec or 00:15:30 ?

Comment: my script need 30 second for excucation

Comment: See my updated answer. It will help you!

Answer (score 1):

In short, cron is not that granular with time. The shortest period you will get is 1 min.

I would use cron to run a script every minute, and make that script run your script four times with a 15-second sleep between runs.

```
 * * * * * sleep 30; some_job
```

**sleep** (30);  //sleep for 30 seconds

That way, you get all the benefits of `cron` as well as your 30 second run period.

Comment: @hpscool This solution run in my side. I hope it will help you.